# CosmosDB-Raise Exception from Stored Proc if Etag does not match

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to upsert document using below Stored Proc . I am passing different types of document in input having same partition key. Some if them are for create and some of them needs to be updated only if Etag matches. If e-Tag does not match my requirement is to throw exception from Stored Procedure which I need to handle in my Java code. Can someone please help me what changes I should make in below SP to handle that.

```
function createEvent(items) {

var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
var count = 0;

if (!items) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null.");

var numItems = items.length;

if (numItems == 0) {
    getContext().getResponse().setBody(0);
    return;
}

tryCreate(items[count], callback);

function tryCreate(item, callback) {
    var options = { disableAutomaticIdGeneration: false };

    var isAccepted = collection.upsertDocument(collectionLink, item, options, callback);
    
    

    if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
}

function callback(err, item, options) {
    if (err) throw err;
    count++;
    if (count >= numItems) {
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
    } else {
        tryCreate(items[count], callback);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't have an example doing this with stored procedures but here is an example using The Cosmos async Java SDK. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-java-sql-api-samples/blob/0ead4ca33dac72c223285e1db866c9dc06f5fb47/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/examples/documentcrud/async/DocumentCRUDQuickstartAsync.java#L366-L418  btw, sprocs are generally only useful when doing multi-document transactions involving more than 10 documents. The Java and .NET SDKs are better choices for transactions with less than that amount as well as bulk data loading, queries and point operations.

Comment: @MarkBrown We were earlier using cosmos batch . But there was a limitation in comos batch of 100 documents(diff types of documents with same partition key) in 1 batch. But we can have bulk usperts at a time so we moved to sprocs as it offers transactional properties as well like cosmos batch.